# Cat data_file n times

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file like this:

```
1
2
3
```

I need to copy data n times with an empty line after each copy. I used these commands

```
#!/bin/sh
num=$(sed -n '1 p' FILE.txt)
for i in {1..  $num }; do cat distance_k.txt >> distance.txt; done
```

n is a number taken from another file 'FILE.txt' (FILE.txt have form like this :

```
90
Abcbaahjfh
...
```

However, it copied only 4 times.
Could you please help me?
Thank you so much!

bash shell

Output

```
1
2
3

1
2
3

1
2
3

1
2
3 

1
2
3

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another kind of loop:

```
num=$(sed -n '1 p' FILE.txt)
for (( i=0; i<num; i++ ))
do
    cat distance_k.txt
    printf '\n'
done >distance.txt
```

If you like, you can use `for (( i=1; i<=num; i++ ))` instead of `for (( i=0; i<num; i++ ))`. It's the same if not using the value of `i`.